# SQLPlus - Data Pump (expdp and impdp)

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, datapump, impdp, expdp

some time ago, I installed Oracle SQLPlus without full Oracle database package.
Now I need expdp and impdp utility. Is it possible to copy important files from a full Oracle installation and pasting them into SQLPlus directory?

Or maybe is there any other option to install only expdp and impdp? (Windows)

Regards,
Kamil

Comment: If this is Windows then no, you need to do the installation of the fat client, unless you are using the instantclient (thin) in which case it might be possible to copy only those binaries.If it's unix then yes, you can copy the entire software folder from source to target using scp -rp.

Comment: Do you need to manage the import/export from your client?  That is, what is the location of the dump files?

Comment: I tried install instantclient (thin) and paste over there dlls and binaries, but I see error like - "the procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.

But, you don't have to actually 'Install' the full client.

Our latest distribution includes an [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) with sql*loader and data pump utilities.

Grab this one

*Instant Client Package - Tools: Includes Data Pump, SQL*Loader and Workload Replay Client*

There's no installer. Just unzip it, and add the directory to your PATH. You should be good to go then.

I wouldn't dump the files into your existing directory where you have SQLPlus though, just put it in a fresh directory and use that instead of your old one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's working, but unfortunately my database use old version and it returns the message - UDE-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 11.2.0.4.0. I understand that there are no such tools for version 11?

Comment: just grab an  11gR2 cilent

Comment: yes, I know, but it is a full package - not only tools. By the way, I already downloaded this client, it takes up a bit more space (1 GB), but that does not matter. Thanks everyone for help.